# Modal Component BsModalRef is not bind on ngOnInit in angular

Tags: angular

Not able to bind data in model popup component using bsModalRef

**Is there anyway to workaround for this issue to handle data in model popup?**

```
itemSummaryResult=[];

showItemSummaryModal(id: number) 
{ 

 this.serverResultsService.getItemDetails(id).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.itemSummaryResult['ItemList'] = data['data'];
  },
  err => { console.log(err); }

);
 this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ItemDetailComponent, { class: 'modal-lg' });
 this.bsModalRef.content.data = this.itemSummaryResult;
}
```

Model Component is as follows

```
itemList=[];

constructor(
public bsModalRef: BsModalRef)

ngOnInit() { 
setTimeout(() => {     
  this.itemList= this.bsModalRef.content.data['ItemList'];        
  }, 1000); 
}
```

Getting data is undefined while trying to assign/get the data from model component

console.log("ItemList",this.bsModalRef.content.data['ItemList'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data while calling `show` method in `initialState` config like this:

```
   this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ItemDetailComponent, {
      initialState: {
        itemList: this.itemSummaryResult
      },
      class: 'modal-lg'
    });
```

And after that, you can use `itemList` in `ModalComponent`. You don't need `setTimeout` anymore

**UPDATE**

There's another issue in your code. You are performing an async operation with `subscribe`. Therefore you need to call `show` method in callback closure of `subscribe`.

```
itemSummaryResult=[];

showItemSummaryModal(id: number) 
{ 

 this.serverResultsService.getItemDetails(id).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.itemSummaryResult['ItemList'] = data['data'];

    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ItemDetailComponent, {
      initialState: {
        itemList: this.itemSummaryResult // Or should it be "this.itemSummaryResult['ItemList']" ?
      },
      class: 'modal-lg'
    });
  },
  err => { 
    console.log(err); 
  }

 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please help me to receive the data in model popup component which we pass in initial state

Comment: You can use `this.itemList` in `ngOnInit` of modal component. Or directly in template like `*ngFor="let item of itemList" `. If this won't help, i could update the answer once i get to my pc.

Comment: Thanks its working as expected but Not able to get the length of the array <span *ngIf="itemList['ItemDetailsByTraceEntityId']"> or <span *ngIf="itemList['ItemDetailsByTraceEntityId'].length">

Comment: What do you get when you log `this.itemList` to the console in `ngOnInit`?

Comment: I get two different array in item list as follows. this.itemList [] - > ItemDetailsById: Array(1) and ItemSummarybyId: Array(1). I want to get the length of itemlist.itemdetailsbyid and itemlist.itemsummarybyid in html or component

Comment: I think your `itemList` should not be an array. It should be an object or map since JavaScript does not have associative arrays. You can use like this: `*ngIf="itemList?.itemdetailsbyid?.length`. If you can create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) project, I can help you further.